# What normalization form does Entity Framework Code First guaranty, if any?

Tags: entity-framework, database-normalization

I'm looking for some information about Entity Framework. Like the title says: What normalization form does Entity Framework Code First guaranty, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not any at all. It's totally(almost totally atleast) up to you how you design your model/database with EF.

Entity Framework is only a way to map between the database and your application code.

Comment: What if your using Code First. Would the answer still be the same? (updated question)

Comment: Thx alot. Accepted your answer.